# Probability and counting cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem goes like this:

"I am given 7 cards from a regular 52 playing card deck."

"Find the probability that there are at least 3 of the cards equally high (e.g. that there are 3 or more jacks). Put up the answer although it is not necessary to calculate the result. Rationalize your solution to the problem."

I put up a solution that looks like this:

$$\frac{13\binom43\binom{49}4+13\binom44\binom{48}3}{\binom{52}7}$$

Is this the right solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a little more complicated than that. Call a hand of seven cards *good* if it contains at least $3$ cards of the same value. The problem is that you’ve counted some good hands twice in your numerator. For instance, the hand with all four aces and all of the kings except the king of clubs is counted once in the term $13\binom43\binom{49}4$ and once again in the term $13\binom44\binom{48}3$; if you replace the ace of spades with the two of spades, the resulting hand is counted twice in the term $13\binom43\binom{49}4$, once for the three aces and once for the three kings.

Try splitting up the possibilities a little more: count separately the hands that have just a three of a kind, the hands that have just a four of a kind, that have two threes of a kind, and that have a three of a kind and a four of a kind.

Comment: I have separated the hands like this:

Hands which have only 3 of a kind:
$13\binom{49}1$

Hands which have only 4 of a kind:
$13\binom{48}1$

Hands which have two threes of a kind:
$13\binom43 12\binom43$

Hands which have a three of a kind and a four of a kind:
$P(13,2)\binom43\binom44$

Are those correct?

Comment: @drleifz: Not quite. Take the first one: there are $13$ ways to pick which rank gets the three of a kind, but then there are $\binom43$ ways to choose which three of the four cards of that rank are chosen. Finally, the remaining four cards can be of four different ranks, of three different ranks with one occurring twice, or of two different ranks, each occurring twice. There are $\binom{12}4$ ways to choose four of the remaining $12$ ranks, and $4^4$ ways to pick one card from each of those ranks, for a total of $4^4\binom{12}4$ ways to pick the last $4$ cards so that they’re all of ...

Comment: ... different ranks. If they’re of $3$ different ranks, there are $12$ ways to pick the rank that occurs twice, $\binom42$ ways to pick $2$ cards of that rank, $\binom{11}2$ ways to pick the other $2$ ranks, and $4^2$ ways to pick one card of each of those ranks, for a total of $12\cdot4^2\binom42\binom{11}2$. And so on. It’s not hard, but it is a bit messy. The easiest case is a three of a kind and a four of a kind: $13$ ways to pick the four of a kind, $12$ ways to pick the rank for the three of a kind, and $4$ ways to pick which card of that rank is *not* included: $13\cdot12\cdot4$.

Comment: Do I need to do this for all of the separated hands?

Comment: @drleifz: You have to make sure that every good hand gets counted exactly once, so yes, each of the categories is going to require some further splitting. The three of a kind category is the worst, though; the others all have fewer possibilities to consider.

Comment: That's true. Sounds like I need a couple of pages for this one :)

Comment: @drleifz: Depends on how big you write. :-) More seriously, what I suggested is the most straightforward approach but not the shortest. If you’re comfortable with the inclusion/exclusion idea, you can get a shorter calculation along the lines that Graham Kemp suggests in his answer.

Comment: I think I would get the best understanding by doing it the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Now I have counted all the possibilities (i think..) and that has left me with the following:

Hands that have exactly 3 of a kind: 
$13*\binom43$ 
where the possibilities for the 4 remaining cards are:
$\binom{12}4*4^4$  // This is four different kinds
$12*4^4*\binom42*\binom{11}2$ // This is 3 different kinds (one comes two times.)
$12*11*4^2$          // This is if there are 2 different kinds

Hands that have exactly four of a kind:
$13*\binom44$
where the possibilities for the remaining cards are:
$\binom{12}3*4^3$ // Three different kinds
$12 * 11 * \binom42 * 4$  // Two different kinds.

Comment: Hands with two three of a kind:
$13 * \binom43 * 12 * \binom43 * \binom{46}1$
Hands with a three of a kind and a four of a kind:
$13 * \binom43 * 12 * \binom44$

So now I am just wondering how I put all this together... And is this a correct counting?

Comment: The pieces are almost right. You should have $4^2$, not $4^4$, in the second piece. In the third piece there are $12$ ways to choose the rank that occurs twice, $\binom42$ ways to pick to cards of that rank, $\binom{10}2$ ways to pick the other $2$ ranks, and $4^2$ ways to pick one card from each, so $12\cdot11\cdot4^2$ is definitely wrong. When you have two threes of a kind, the extra card must come from the $44$ cards that aren’t of those ranks, not from the $46$ cards that you haven’t chosen already. The others are okay. To put them together, you need to add up the possibilities. This ...

Comment: ... easy with the ones in the second half of your comment. In the one three-of-a-kind case you have to add up all of the ways to choose the other four cards and then multiply that by the $13\binom43$ ways to pick the three-of-a-kind. The four-of-a-kind case is similar.

Comment: What I just did is that I calculated all the hands. Meaning that first I calculated how many ways I can draw 7 cards with 3 the same rank and the other 4 of different ranks, the other four of 3 different ranks (1 rank occurring twice), the other four of 2 different ranks (with 2 ranks occurring twice). Then I added the outcome of those and got how many possibilities it is to draw 7 cards with exactly 3 of the same rank. And then I did the same with the other ranks and then I summed all the outcomes together and divided with $\binom{52}7$. How does that sound? It gave me 7,8% probability.

Comment: @drleifz: I think that you’re off just a bit: I get a little less than $7,7$%. Part of the problem may be that I made some typos in the comment in which I gave some calculations. Here are the subtotals that I get: $4$ & $3$: $624$; two $3$s: $54.912$; just $4$: $224.224$; just $3$: 10.007.712. Total:10.287.472

Answer (score 1):

> "Find the probability that there are at least 3 of the cards equally high (e.g. that there are 3 or more jacks). Put up the answer although it is not necessary to calculate the result. Rationalize your solution to the problem."

You have the probability space counted right: ${52\choose 7}$

For the favourable events you need to use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to count ways to get either 3 or 4 cards of any one face, and discount ways to get exactly 3 cards each of *two* faces, or 4 cards of one face and 3 cards of another.

$$\frac{\overbrace{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{48\choose 4}}^\text{3 suits of 1 face}+\overbrace{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 4}{48\choose 3}}^\text{4 suits of 1 face}-\overbrace{{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}}^\text{3 suits each of 2 faces}-\overbrace{{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}}^\text{3 suits of 1 face 4 suits of another} }{52\choose 7}$$

Comment: Isn't this similar to the method described above? Although this is a little bit more constructive

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to find the probability of the complementary event, and then subtract from 1.

If we don't have 3 cards of the same rank, then there are 4 possibilities:

1) 7 singletons $\;$
2) 1 pair and 5 singletons$\;$
3) 2 pairs and 3 singletons$\;$
4) 3 pairs and 1 singleton.

This gives a probability of

$1-\displaystyle\frac{\binom{13}{7}4^7+\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{5}4^5+\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{11}{3}4^3+\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}^3\binom{10}{1}4}{\binom{52}{7}}$.